# Asset pipeline issue when running cap deploy:update on Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

Deploying an app first time with Capistrano, but having problem running the cap deploy:update task on Rails 3.1.3, Capistrano 2.9.0, RVM 1.8.6 and Ubuntu server 10.10. Should not be a permissions issue as far as I can see. Been banging my head against this now for a while, thankful for any directions.

```
drphil@mumindalen:~/Rails/testapp$ cap deploy:update
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@my_server:~/testapp/ HEAD"
git@23.23.23.23.'s password: 
command finished in 8892ms
  * executing "git clone -q git@my_server:~/testapp/         /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654 && cd /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654 && git checkout -q -b deploy f473e207b15d73d2fa9aa32ab1dbeec98471153d && (echo f473e207b15d73d2fa9aa32ab1dbeec98471153d > /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/REVISION)"
servers: ["my_server"]
Password: 
[my_server] executing command
command finished in 1695ms
* executing `deploy:finalize_update'
triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
* executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
* executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/assets &&\\\n        mkdir -p /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public &&\\\n        mkdir -p /home/deploy/testapp/shared/assets &&\\\n        ln -s /home/deploy/testapp/shared/assets /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/assets"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
command finished in 1117ms
* executing "chmod -R g+w /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
command finished in 614ms
* executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/log /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/system /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/tmp &&\\\n      ln -s /home/deploy/testapp/shared/log /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/log &&\\\n      ln -s /home/deploy/testapp/shared/system /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/system &&\\\n      ln -s /home/deploy/testapp/shared/pids /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/tmp/pids"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
command finished in 1022ms
* executing "find /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/images /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/stylesheets /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/pu## Heading ##blic/javascripts -exec touch -t 201112111837.12 {} ';'; true"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
*** [err :: my_server] find:
*** [err :: my_server] "/home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/images"
*** [err :: my_server] : Filen eller katalogen finns inte
*** [err :: my_server] 
*** [err :: my_server] find:
*** [err :: my_server] "/home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/stylesheets"
*** [err :: my_server] : Filen eller katalogen finns inte
*** [err :: my_server] 
*** [err :: my_server] find:
*** [err :: my_server] "/home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654/public/javascripts"
*** [err :: my_server] : Filen eller katalogen finns inte
*** [err :: my_server] 
command finished in 1024ms
triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
*** [err :: my_server] sh:
*** [err :: my_server] rake: not found
*** [err :: my_server] 
command finished in 1440ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654; true"
servers: ["my_server"]
[my_server] executing command
command finished in 727ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deploy/testapp/releases/20111211183654 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on my_server
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was an issue with different versions of RVM on the development box and the server and that I had not [set up deploy.rb properly](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/) to work with RVM. Been digging around for hours thinking it was some kind of [bug](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/43#issuecomment-1891004). Oh well.

Got it working using this in deploy.rb:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p290'
set :rvm_type, :user
```

Answer (score 0):

It could't find rake binary.
If you are using RVM, make sure the user which you are deploying as is in rvm group.

Or, most likely (or in combination with the above), you have .bashrc / bashrc / profile environment disabled for non-interactive shells. Thus it doesn't load all configuration (set PATH etc.).

See http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Jun/msg00251.html

Debian (/etc/bashrc):

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

...and so on.
The last line is the problem. It quits processing bashrc for non-interactive shells.
Look for something similar on your system.

UPDATE:

There is an overview of shell scripts that are processed on debian squeeze:
http://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/~schamane/_/blog:110814_bash_shell_startup_files_in_debian_squeeze

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were right but it being a RVM issue, but .bashrc was being sourced from .bash_profile already.